# Problem in getting the initial value of FK field in django form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

This are my models:

```
class Aggrement(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    act         = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    section     = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    category_ls = (
            ('General','General'),
            ('Specific','Specific'),
            )
    category    = models.CharField(max_length=32,choices=category_ls,default='General')
    textbody    = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True,config_name='special')
    guideline   = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.act

class User_aggrement(models.Model):
    User        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="Users_aggrement",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    aggrement   = models.ForeignKey(Aggrement,related_name="Users_aggrement",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    textbody    = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True,config_name='special')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

I want to get the value of the field `textbody` of `Aggrement` model in `textbody` of `User_aggrement` model.

i.e. when `User` will try to create an `instance` of `User_aggrement` model the `textbody` field should get the value of `textbody` in `Aggrement` model in the form field.

Is this possible in django?
Any idea?

Comment: which instance of `Aggrement`? It depends how you determine which one. If that's always known, then you can hook up a handler for the `pre_save` signal of `User_aggrement` to populate `textbody` before saving. Or if it depends on some parameters during the request, do that in the view (or form) that saves the `User_aggrement`.

Comment: oh, I see you have a foreign key, then just use that during the `pre_save`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
class User_aggrement(models.Model):
    User        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name="Users_aggrement",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    aggrement   = models.ForeignKey(Aggrement,related_name="Users_aggrement",on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    textbody    = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True,config_name='special')

    def save(*args, **kwargs):
        self.textbody = self.aggrement.textbody
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

You don't need to handle it in forms.

Comment: How can I do the same in views?